# keep getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I am trying to send a jpeg image using expressjs api. But I am keep getting below error.

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/1.0/profile/avatar", ok: false, …}
error
:
error
:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48937:37) at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4973:33) at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581) at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834) at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16794) at p (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27648) at XMLHttpRequest.v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27893)
text
:
"����JFIF���   
( %!1!%3+...383,7(-.+↵↵↵+++++++++++++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++����"����7!1AQaq���"23�4BRr����#b���������?��N��:0b��[�ǽW_ݏ�g�ؚ��ez���Mgi�↵��r��Fw&":����Rfr�G��+�r��]^�~��]qD{��93\�6���/���3�u��� n��f~M5O�1ݽ]��T�umN�S�����ﶱ;���f.TN(�*��[@.܋V����P���\ν)���3?�#i�_L����},^�3��:�n�Ȼn&��K���������P��ʣ�z'*�j:X\������(��=S��M9Y�ݗ� �2q?�������^XF���^�i���V�G-'��↵ O�MWziNQ��8i�t�q����z3��.�/�ʯ�j���~�O|�$��/F�U���=S��[��LWĢ�m{�O-�A�k�t�9�DϞ�֭�[��r[�،=Q�3��� �Z�t�Q�I����~���[Ld4�j��x��n�V�5O(�;����>;^�;�=���7��3Nt��~��������LG��0
↵b�]=.����|�qt����67ZcL�gH�&��/r*�M1�D������{�T�Y�y� ժ��؝p�����nҏ�nt19O8�ǒ�.#E��:�
:ϏRu�}w�r����O����ܩ���L�����\�2z')�~K\m7���b+�ϹɌ���;8��|3�uU�7��T������>`�9�i�:��ň�TZҏ~�ͼ�o��|s�?��#�<G�Α=*���������F��}e��rz�h���]�������^M�8�N��˶5�-Ӏ~����9�11�O�[�mU������O-1����S-܋��nbc��1��p�|U��J����'*i7=��L�ҟ�E9:ۮmW�������<db#*�����$;L�k��x�������O�@d#p���"
__proto__
:
Object
headers
:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
:
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/api/1.0/profile/avatar"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
url
:
"http://localhost:3000/api/1.0/profile/avatar"
```

Below is my code. What I am trying to do here is that I get an image from directory and send send it over after writing head to it. I am not sure why am I getting this error. Any idea how to overcome this?

```
let imagepath = __dirname + '/../images/avatar.jpeg';
let image = fs.readFileSync(imagepath);
let mime = fileType(image).mime;

console.log(image);

response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mime });
response.end(image, 'binary');
```

Here is update for my client side code.

```
    let myHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
        'withCredentials': 'true',
        'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')
    });

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/1.0/profile/avatar', { headers: myHeaders });
```

UPDATE for this question.

So I replaced the `this.http.get` with following

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/1.0/profile/avatar', { headers: myHeaders, responseType: 'blob', }).map(blob => {
        let urlCreator = window.URL;
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob));
    });
```

which is returning response which is base64. Now I tried to render that base64 image using `img` tag but somehow it is not rendering. Below is the code I am using for rendering.

```
this.profileService.getUserAvatar().subscribe(avatar => {
            response[0]['image'] = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(avatar);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

  this.profile = response; // this.profile works fine. when I console.log this.profile then is show property image which I use in template below to render.
```

here is the html

```
<div *ngFor="let p of profile">
        <img [src]="p.image">
    </div>
```

Comment: Your server works fine. It's your client that for some reason interprets it as a json.

Comment: It looks like that error is coming from client side code, trying to parse the response, but you're showing server side code.

Comment: @zerkms fastest gun in the west

Comment: It seems like you guys are right but when I set `'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'` still same issue.

Comment: @null it's impossible to suggest anything else unless you provide your client code

Comment: @null it's not the content type header you need to change, it's what's done with the data when it comes back (sometimes referred to as dataType from jquery days). What is `this.http` in your client code? Is that a module for making http requests you're pulling in? You'd have to look at what happens in `this.http.get` when the result returns.

Comment: I still haven't got this working. Anyone who can help me with this out?